# How to stop deprecation warning?

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, deprecated, numba

My function has to be jit compiled, but I get the following deprecation warning:

How can I solve this, so the issue is fixed? (so that i dont have to be afraid of the function not working properly in the future)

```
e_labeling.py:418: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "get_result" failed type inference due to: non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
During: typing of argument at D:/Arc/Arc_Project\Architecture\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py (422)

File "..\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py", line 422:
    def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result):
        <source elided>
        
        for i in prange(len_result):
        ^

  @nb.jit
D:/Arc/Arc_Project\Architecture\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py:418: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "get_result" failed type inference due to: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.core.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>

File "..\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py", line 422:
    def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result):
        <source elided>
        
        for i in prange(len_result):
        ^

  @nb.jit
c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:177: NumbaWarning: Function "get_result" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.

File "..\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py", line 422:
    def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result):
        <source elided>
        
        for i in prange(len_result):
        ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:187: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "..\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py", line 422:
    def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result):
        <source elided>
        
        for i in prange(len_result):
        ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg,
D:/Arc/Arc_Project\Architecture\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py:418: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "get_result" failed type inference due to: non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at D:/Arc/Arc_Project\Architecture\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py (422)

File "..\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py", line 422:
    def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result):
        <source elided>
        
        for i in prange(len_result):
        ^

  @nb.jit
c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:177: NumbaWarning: Function "get_result" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True.

File "..\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py", line 422:
    def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result):
        <source elided>
        
        for i in prange(len_result):
        ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:187: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "..\_3_Labeling\CRV_Weighted_Score_labeling.py", line 422:
    def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result):
        <source elided>
        
        for i in prange(len_result):
        ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg,
```

It creates a 5th array of random values `result` und sets either `1`s or `0`s depending on the condition: (yes theres 2 conditions for each, but this is because they have to be checked in a different order.

`RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices` are numpy arrays of objects (because its numpy arrays of numpy arrays of different sizes. (at the same index the sub arrays of those 4 np.arrays are the same lenght)

Here is the function:(at the bottom there is a reproducable sample)

```
from numba import prange
@nb.njit 
def compare_size_filter(a,b): 
    return a > b 
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def loop_func(sub_RatiosUp, sub_RatiosDown, sub_UpPointsSlices, sub_DownPointsSlices, sub_result, len_shape):
     for j in prange(len_shape): 
        if compare_size_filter(sub_RatiosUp[j],sub_RatiosDown[j]):
            sub_result[j] = 1
        elif compare_size_filter(sub_RatiosDown[j],sub_RatiosUp[j]):
            sub_result[j] = 0
        elif compare_size_filter(sub_DownPointsSlices[j], sub_UpPointsSlices[j]): 
            sub_result[j] = 0
        else:                       
            sub_result[j] = 1  
@nb.jit
def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result): 
    for i in prange(len_result):
       loop_func(RatiosUp[i], RatiosDown[i], UpPointsSlices[i], DownPointsSlices[i], result[i], shapes[i]) 
    return result
```

reproducable sample: (with a correct result list-comprehension to make sure, the result is still correct after changing anything)

````
import numpy as np, numba as nb, time

# generate sample data
LEN = 1000; Amount_Of_Elements = 4000
temp = np.random.randint(Amount_Of_Elements*0.7,high=Amount_Of_Elements, size=LEN) 
RatiosUp         = np.array([np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp], dtype=object)
RatiosDown       = np.array([np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp], dtype=object)
UpPointsSlices   = np.array([np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp], dtype=object)
DownPointsSlices = np.array([np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp], dtype=object)  
 
# this is the original result without numba (== same result as above when used without decorators)
correct_result      = [ 
[1 if (ratUp >ratDown)  else 0 if (ratDown>ratUp) else  0 if (pointsDown>pointsUp) else 1    
              for ratUp,ratDown,pointsUp,pointsDown  
                          in zip(ratiosUpSlice,ratiosDownSlice,upPointsSlice,downPointsSlice)] 
                                        for ratiosUpSlice,ratiosDownSlice,upPointsSlice,downPointsSlice 
                                                   in zip(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices)]

from numba import prange
@nb.njit 
def compare_size_filter(a,b): 
    return a > b 
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def loop_func(sub_RatiosUp, sub_RatiosDown, sub_UpPointsSlices, sub_DownPointsSlices, sub_result, len_shape):
     for j in prange(len_shape): 
        if compare_size_filter(sub_RatiosUp[j],sub_RatiosDown[j]):
            sub_result[j] = 1
        elif compare_size_filter(sub_RatiosDown[j],sub_RatiosUp[j]):
            sub_result[j] = 0
        elif compare_size_filter(sub_DownPointsSlices[j], sub_UpPointsSlices[j]): 
            sub_result[j] = 0
        else:                       
            sub_result[j] = 1  
@nb.jit
def get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes, result, len_result): 
    for i in prange(len_result):
       loop_func(RatiosUp[i], RatiosDown[i], UpPointsSlices[i], DownPointsSlices[i], result[i], shapes[i]) 
    return result 


shapes   = np.asarray([arr.size for arr in RatiosUp],dtype=np.object)
result   = np.asarray([np.empty(s,np.int8) for s in shapes],dtype=np.object) 
    
result1 = get_result(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, shapes,result, nb.int64(len(result)))

test = all(np.allclose(a,b, equal_nan=True) for a,b in zip(correct_result,result1.tolist()))
print(test)```

EDIT: (to avoid misunderstandings)

its not about supression, but what i have to do different so that it wont be deprecated in the future.
````

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress deprecation warnings. From the [warnings filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)

```
from numba.core.errors import NumbaDeprecationWarning, NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaDeprecationWarning)
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning)
```

EDIT: From our comments below, I see this isn't doing it for you. So I took a look at what you provided and noticed that you're not sending the data types Numba needs.

You're sending it a NumPy arrays.

```
RatiosUp = np.array([np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp], dtype=object)
```

When it needs something more like this for an array

```
>>> numba.float32[:]
array(float32, 1d, A)
```

Again, from the documentation:

> [As an optimizing compiler, Numba needs to decide on the type of each
> variable to generate efficient machine code. Python’s standard types
> are not precise enough for that, so we had to develop our own
> fine-grained type system](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html).

Comment: its not about supression, but what i have to do different so that it wont be deprecated in the future. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding :(

Comment: Unless you are a core developer, you don't know (and probably won't if they don't have a roadmap published) what will or won't be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Otherwise, you should refer to the link the error message: (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit)

Comment: Oh, I see it. You're sending it the wrong data type.

Comment: forceobj=False did it -> its slower

is there a way to convert a np.array of objects into something like a nb array of nb.objects? couldnt find nb.objects. Or are there arrays of arrays of variable size? because Im currently using np.object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221727/discussion-between-hrokr-and-la-li-lu-le-low).

Comment: what can I do with the variable size numpy arrays?
is there something like 2d numpy of float32 but with variable sizes?